# Entity framework and n-layered application

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

so, I have this:

1. Web App
2. Business Logic
3. Data Access Logic

I created in the data access logic, the entities, the context, the initializer.

SO usually the higher layers, call the lower layer functionality, right?

If I want to save a customer, I want to create a Customer entity from the web app. What I dont like is having a direct reference from the web app layer to the data access logic layer (class library)

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it on a previous project

**4 Projects under my Solution**

**1)** UI ( my ASP.NET MVC Application)

**2)** Business Entities ( My POCOS's for Entities like Customer, Order etc..)

**3)** Business Logic ( My Inermediate Service Layer which stays in between UI and DataAccess layer. I  would do my business specific validations here.

**4)** The Data Access Layer. Talks to my database. Can be EF / pure ADO.NET Stored Proc etc..

- DataAccessLayer Project  has references of Business Entities Project
- Business Logic Project has refereces of Business Entities Project
- UI Project has refereces of Business Entities Project and BusinessLogic.

From UI, I call methods of Middle Layer (Business Logic) and from there after doing custom validations / business rules, i would call Data Access Layer methods.

Comment: what is the pros and cons when you expose your Business Entities to all layers instead of write customized data transfer objects in your service layer ? does your UI layer have ability to access the DB access object ?

Comment: @null: In the above approach, The Data Acces Layer returns the loaded Business objects. ex : for a GetUser method, it returns a User Entity object defined in Business Entity project, like an ORM. These objects represents almost same as the db entities. For Customized UI entities,  I would use ViewModels.

Comment: My solution is a generatlized version which supports non -Entity framework scenario as well. If im using EF, i dont create the POCO in my business objects. I use those and map those to my ViewModel in mapping layer

Answer (score 1):

I know this probably isn't very constructive but if I was you I would just add the reference. There no point making things harder on your self to find a more complicated way to do something which should be easy. plus if you skip it now and come across a better solution later you can just modify your code.